# How to get Nginx to refuse SSL/TLS connections where host is an IP or doesn't match a server_name

Tags: nginx, ssl, https

For our PCI complicance we've starting getting the below failure:

[image]

We use Nginx for our web server. When accessing the webserver using any of our domain names, we have the correct `server_name` values in the Nginx config and as such present the correct certificates. The security scan is also scanning the IP address of the server directly and getting caught in one of the `server` blocks. How can we either prevent this getting caught or respond in a suitable way such that we don't get this error with the security scan?

I've found ideas [like this which returns a 404](https://blog.knoldus.com/nginx-disable-direct-access-via-http-and-https-to-a-website-using-ip/), but that won't help as the CN will still not match that of the IP address.

This is what the server block which it catching the request looks like (it is actually a redirect from an old domain to a newer domain, but as you can see is not explicitly listing as the `default_server` as per the [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html)):

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name xxxx.de www.xxxx.de;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_certificate /xxxx/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /xxxx/xxxx.de.key;

    return 301 https://www.yyyy.de;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Why do you believe that returning an error status code on an explicit default_server will not meet your requirements? Are you required to serve non-SNI clients at all?

Comment: @anx good point, I don't know if that will meet the requirements. If I implement that and test it in a web browser, before seeing the http error (in this case I used 403), I'm told about the security certificate issue. I assumed that the security scan would reject on on the certificate issue first too, but that's just an assumption. I'm re-running a scan now to see if the certificate miss-match with a 403 passes the requirements. Thanks

Comment: The solution was apparently to create self-signed certificates for the IPs and return our error code using them instead of the certificate for the domain name, and then Security Metrics are able to set an override to allow self-signed certificates. They cannot override to allow a wrong hostname - despite running the scan on the IP not the hostname. A bit silly if you ask me!

Answer (score 2):

If you want non-SNI clients to default to something compliant, you will have to add an explicit default_server. Note that as per [nginx docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen), the first is implicitly used as default:

> If none of the directives have the default_server parameter then the first server with the address:port pair will be the default server for this pair.

There are some semi-appropriate http status codes to signal inability to produce a response for a given server name, but simply disconnecting after presenting an empty (no FQDN in CN) self-signed certificate is most likely to ensure that the verification tool ignores the certificate:

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl default_server;
  server_name _;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/snakeoil.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/snakeoil.key;
  return 444;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is basically the same as I implemented and whilst it does seem like a sensible idea, it's not worked in practice with the company Security Metrics. +1 for a decent idea which will probably help others

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the IP address as the server_name of your http port 80 server and then use

```
return 301 https://site$request_uri;
```

For example:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name xxxx.de www.xxxx.de 111.112.113.114;

    return 301 https://www.yyyy.de$request_uri;
}
```

Edit:
This doesn't actually answer your question of refusing the connection but rather fixing the issue so it should redirect the query properly to your website.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I can’t see that this will make any difference as they are connecting over https to port 443. If they weren’t they wouldn’t be getting into the above quote server block. I’m not trying to redirect http traffic to https. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: Ah, my apologies, I misunderstood the question!